# How do I remove the symbols near the authors names in Achemso?

Tags: achemso

By using the Achemso package, I encountered the following problem:
I have a list of authors, all with the same affiliation, except for one that has also a new affiliation.

```
\author{Author 1}
\author{Author 2}
\altaffiliation{X}
\author{Author 3}
\affiliation{ABC}
```

This code will correctly assign the affiliation to each author, but all the author names are followed by the same symbol, so the output looks like this:

Author1†, Author2†‡, Author3†

† ABC
  ‡ X

How can I remove the symbol which is common to all authors and get this?

Author1, Author2‡, Author3
   ABC
   ‡ X

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you should not do this, because this gives you a lonely footnote.

This having said, here is how you can achieve it. But you have to mess a little with internals of the `achemso` package.

First alter the symbols for the footnotes (I don't know if this has any side effects):

```
\renewcommand*{\acs@author@fnsymbol@symbol}[1]{%
\ifcase #1 *\or
    {}\or
    \dagger\or
    \ddagger\or
        \P\or
        \S\or
            \|\or
            \bot\or
                \#\or
                @\or
                    \triangle\or
                    \nabla
    \fi
}
```

Now the symbol for the first affilation has vanished, but you still have two delete the comma, that was originally between the two symbols. This can be done with

```
\renewcommand*\acs@author@affil@alt@aux{%
\expandafter\acs@affil@marker@cnt
    \csname @author@altaffil@\@roman\@tempcnta\endcsname\relax
\advance\acs@affil@marker@cnt\acs@affil@cnt\relax
\advance\acs@affil@marker@cnt\acs@footnote@cnt\relax
\protected@edef\acs@author@footnotes{%
    \acs@author@footnotes
    {}%
    \acs@author@fnsymbol{\acs@affil@marker@cnt}%
}%
}
```

So the final MWE looks like:

```
\documentclass{achemso}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\acs@author@fnsymbol@symbol}[1]{%
\ifcase #1 *\or
    {}\or
    \dagger\or
    \ddagger\or
        \P\or
        \S\or
            \|\or
            \bot\or
                \#\or
                @\or
                    \triangle\or
                    \nabla
    \fi
}

\renewcommand*\acs@author@affil@alt@aux{%
\expandafter\acs@affil@marker@cnt
    \csname @author@altaffil@\@roman\@tempcnta\endcsname\relax
\advance\acs@affil@marker@cnt\acs@affil@cnt\relax
\advance\acs@affil@marker@cnt\acs@footnote@cnt\relax
\protected@edef\acs@author@footnotes{%
    \acs@author@footnotes
    {}%
    \acs@author@fnsymbol{\acs@affil@marker@cnt}%
}%
}

\makeatother

\title{Title}

\author{Author 1}
\affiliation{ABC}
\author{Author 2}
\altaffiliation{X}
\author{Author 3}
\affiliation{ABC}


\begin{document}

\end{document}
```